# coveralls.io (or any other): coverage of generated files (which are not in git)

Tags: code-coverage, coveralls

I am searching for any coverage report host/service/web which can visualize coverage for generated files.

I am currently using coveralls.io and it seems that it can not handle generated files and I do not know how to post them to coveralls.io so they can be viewed.

```
Source Not Available
The file "..." isn't available on github.
Either it's been removed, or the repo root directory needs to be updated.
```

https://coveralls.io/builds/25612947/source?filename=include/hdlConvertor/verilogPreproc/verilogPreprocParser/verilogPreprocParserBaseVisitor.h

- Generated files may change build to build and are very large and I simply can not add them to git. But I need to know the coverage.
- Currently I am only able to watch coverage for generated files locally.
- I know the list of generated files and I can upload them during the build If I know where.

Comment: Actually, there seems to be API for posting files https://docs.coveralls.io/api-reference SOURCE FILE/source

Comment: I am using coveralls-lcov, it seems that the requested functionality can be added if not already present https://github.com/okkez/coveralls-lcov/issues/15

Comment: It seems that coveralls-lcov always posts the files and coveralls.io just somehow ignores it.